# With XSL-FO/Antenna house formatter 6.6, can an image be scaled to always fit on the page?

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I find many similar questions, but not this: I have xml documents with markup for images which don't specify image dimensions. The image widths and heights are always smaller than a page if they are not scaled up and start at the top of the page.

The images are not inline (external-graphic is within a block). They always have a title (text) before them. If the image is wide, it works to use scale-to-fit and width 100%. If the image is tall, it runs off the bottom of the page, if the height is set large enough, and has keep-with-previous="always".

Before calling the XSL formatter, I know the pixel dimensions of the images (all raster), and I know the accumulated top and bottom margins

Is there a way to make sure the image will always fit on the page, when it's tall?

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-height="100%"` to the `fo:external-graphic`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#max-height)

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" space-before="1lh">Figure title</fo:block>
<fo:block keep-with-previous="always" text-align="center">
  <fo:external-graphic width="100%" max-height="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit"
                       src="formatter-V7_V.jpg" />
</fo:block>
<fo:block space-before="1lh">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</fo:block>
<fo:block font-weight="bold" space-before="1lh">Figure title</fo:block>
<fo:block keep-with-previous="always" text-align="center">
  <fo:external-graphic width="100%" max-height="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit"
                       src="formatter-V7_H.jpg" />
</fo:block>
<fo:block font-weight="bold" space-before="1lh">Figure title</fo:block>
<fo:block keep-with-previous="always" text-align="center">
  <fo:external-graphic width="100%" max-height="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit"
                       src="formatter-V7_V.jpg" />
</fo:block>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That probably fits with what I asked, but what I meant by keeping within the page was to be pushed onto the next page if it's too high.

A twist is that the images are all tiny, so they look too small if their natural dimensions are used. The solution you provide works if the image is placed around the middle of the page. If the image would be placed below that, it gets smaller as it is placed down further until it's too small.

If there is no height/width/scale supplied and the image is tall, setting it's height and having keep-with-previous="always" force it onto the next page.

Comment: The end of the previous comment was meant to be: If there is no height/width/scale supplied and the image is tall, setting it's height and having keep-with-previous="always" force it onto the next page, is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Because the images are small and you're using Antenna House Formatter, there's `axf:image-resolution` (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.image-resolution) for setting the resolution of individual graphics. If you set related graphics to the same, fairly low DPI, you'll get a far more consistent appearance than by scaling every graphic to fill the available width.

If a fixed low DPI mostly works but makes some images too wide/high, you could also or instead use `allowed-width-scale` and/or `allowed-height-scale` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#allowed-height-scale) to get a few controlled scales. (I've never combined `axf:image-resolution` with either, myself, but that might be what you want.)

Or you could try `axf:image-resolution` with `content-width="scale-down-to-fit"` so that larger graphics fill the width of the text block.

Because you know the sizes of the images, you could also set `min-height` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#min-height) based on some scale factor applied to the images so that the images can't be too small, either.